# SyncProxy errors while inserting to database : Android and GWT

Tags: java, android, tomcat, gwt, couchdb

While using SyncProxy, various errors and exceptions are counted. Also when I run app in my mobile,it forcefully closes.

Note: I already have deployed WAR file at tomcat server.

Logcat dumps

```
07-08 00:55:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(20103): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
07-08 00:55:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(20103): Process: com.example.rpc, PID: 20103
07-08 00:55:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(20103): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-08 00:55:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(20103):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
07-08 00:55:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(20103):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
07-08 00:55:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(20103):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
07-08 00:55:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(20103):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
07-08 00:55:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(20103):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-08 00:55:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(20103):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-08 00:55:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(20103):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-08 00:55:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(20103):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-08 00:55:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(20103): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.gdevelop.gwt.syncrpc.SyncProxy
07-08 00:55:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(20103):    at com.regs.server.snp.doInBackground(snp.java:27)
07-08 00:55:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(20103):    at com.regs.server.snp.doInBackground(snp.java:1)
07-08 00:55:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(20103):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-08 00:55:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(20103):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-08 00:55:37.733: E/AndroidRuntime(20103):    ... 4 more
```

Code : http://pastebin.com/X054k2dg

Comment: Looks like a packaging issue: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.gdevelop.gwt.syncrpc.SyncProxy`

Comment: But i have already set the class path for the same jar file.